# ruby on rails and bootstrap 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I am using Rails 5.1 and Bootstrap 4 to develop a website, now I want to add glyphicons to the website, but Bootstrap 4 doesn't have those anymore. This site provides glyphicons https://glyphicons.com/ but I do not know how to include them into the application. Can someone please explain to me how to do this, which files do I need to change or modify, which lines of code to use, or console commands if necessary, in order to use these glyphicons. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website does have an [Examples of use](https://glyphicons.com/examples-of-use/) section. Depending on which license you are looking can change how you use them in your app.

If you are going to be using the Free version then you would have to download the `zip` file that contains all the icons as `png`'s. Add these icons to your `assets/images` directory and you could then use an [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) to display the icons.

If you want to check out additional icons to use you can review the [Icons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/) section within the Bootstrap docs.

Comment: I will use free version, okay, that is one way to go around. I hope they will have some styling. Thank You

Comment: One more question, I have found this guide for the glyphicons http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ in here it say I could apparently use gems to include this to the rails application, so is this all I need to do, and do I need sass or less version for Rails 5.1, I am newbie so I am still getting around, please help?

Comment: You can either use the cdn or use the [font-awesome](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem. Follow the installation instructions. If I have helped you with your original question please accept the answer.

Comment: Oh well I will just use the gem if it provides all the functionality, answer accepted